# subString log using regex pattern

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, log4j2

I need to get the black part from this log4j2 log using a regex pattern without script, and I do not know how
thanks

2021-07-15 08:47:59,466 [DE][Receiving message '<200,{"data":{"returnCode":"00"}},[Expires:"-1", Cache-Control:"no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate", Access-Control-Allow-Headers:"Accept-Encoding, Accept, Content-Type, tsec, consumerrequestid, authenticationchallenge, authenticationtype, authenticationdata, authenticationstate, contactid, consumeruuid, consumerapplicationid, perimetertsec, authorization, responsewarningcode, responsewarningdescription, cuf, prefer, phoneNumber, Location, X-RHO-PARENTSPANID, X-RHO-TRACEID, preferredauthenticationtype, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, iv-remote-address, thirdparty-x-forwarded-for, thirdparty-user-agent, thirdparty-geolocation, thirdparty-calculated-scoring, thirdparty-deviceid, vnd.bbva.security-client-certificate, order-preferredaction, authenticationresponse, Access-Control-Max-Age, BCS-Device-Id, BCS-Device-OS-Name, BCS-Device-Model-Name, BCS-Device-Model-Manufacturer, BCS-Device-Screen-Size, BCS-Device-OS-Version, BCS-Device-DPI, BCS-Device-App-Name, BCS-Device-App-Version, Third-Party-Application-Id, ECS-Signature-Platform-Use-Case, BCS-Process-Code, BCS-Operation-Tracer, BCS-Process-Tracer, order-preferredaction, order-id, order-accepteddisclaimers", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Pragma:"no-cache", Referrer-Policy:"same-origin", Content-Security-Policy:"script-src 'self'", Date:"Thu, 15 Jul 2021 06:47:59 GMT", Connection:"keep-alive", Strict-Transport-Security:"max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains", Transfer-Encoding:"chunked", Access-Control-Allow-Methods:"GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH", old-catalog:"true", X-Frame-Options:"sameorigin", Access-Control-Expose-Headers:"Accept-Encoding, Accept, Content-Type, tsec, consumerrequestid, authenticationchallenge, authenticationtype, authenticationdata, authenticationstate, contactid, consumeruuid, consumerapplicationid, perimetertsec, authorization, responsewarningcode, responsewarningdescription, cuf, prefer, phoneNumber, Location, X-RHO-PARENTSPANID, X-RHO-TRACEID, preferredauthenticationtype, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, iv-remote-address, thirdparty-x-forwarded-for, thirdparty-user-agent, thirdparty-geolocation, thirdparty-calculated-scoring, thirdparty-deviceid, vnd.bbva.security-client-certificate, order-preferredaction, authenticationresponse, Access-Control-Max-Age, BCS-Device-Id, BCS-Device-OS-Name, BCS-Device-Model-Name, BCS-Device-Model-Manufacturer, BCS-Device-Screen-Size, BCS-Device-OS-Version, BCS-Device-DPI, BCS-Device-App-Name, BCS-Device-App-Version, Third-Party-Application-Id, ECS-Signature-Platform-Use-Case, BCS-Process-Code, BCS-Operation-Tracer, BCS-Process-Tracer, order-preferredaction, order-id, order-accepteddisclaimers", **tsec:"eJxtlNmKq1gARX/lUq+hSo0zVBXE2Tgbx7w0Rz0O0TjH6eu7Grov96FfN"**, Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*", consumerrequestid:"c580c0cd-4589-4156", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", Content-Type:"application/json; charset=UTF-8"]>'

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code/regex in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Use: `tsec:".*?"`, [Check the demo here](https://regex101.com/r/Ly8jto/1).

Comment: thanks, I use <pattern>%d [/tsec:".*?"/gm] %n</pattern> 
but the result is not the same...